# How to create PHP image object from downloaded image?

Tags: php, image, curl, image-processing, getimagesize

So I've been using this approach to resize images uploaded via forms in PHP:

```
list ($width, $height, $type, $w)=getimagesize($_FILES[$imageName]['tmp_name']);
$info = getimagesize($_FILES[$imageName]['tmp_name']);
```

This works well - allows resizing & conversion to png.

Now I need to do the same thing - but for downloaded images, e.g. given the url of an image online such as `http://colorvisiontesting.com/images/plate%20with%205.jpg`.

From the looks of it this can be done with `CURL`, but I can't quite work out how to then create an image object from it. This is what I have so far:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $imageURL);
$curlImage = curl_exec($c);
$err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

list ($width, $height, $type, $w)=getimagesize($curlImage);
$info = getimagesize($curlImage);
```

But this is failing at `getimagesize` - and I can't work out what the correct approach is here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) function works on filename (local or remote) but not on a string which represents the content of your image.

You can:

1. Save that content to a local file (using [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), for example)
2. Use the [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) function on the remote file (it should work).
3. Use the [`getimagesizefromstring`](http://www.php.net/getimagesizefromstring) (which works the same as `getimagesize` but works in data and not filename)
4. Use the [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring) (which you need if you want to convert your stream/data to image (gd) resource, and then use the `imagesx` and `imagesy` on the resouce.